# Why are my Bootstrap column classes stacking instead of sitting alongside one another in a row?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've just setup Bootstrap 3.0 and following a tutorial by William Helfi:
[William Helfi Bootstrap Tutorial](http://www.williamghelfi.com/blog/2013/06/09/bootstrap-3-the-new-grid-system-for-starters/)

The issue I'm having is that my columns of class 'col-md-6 are stacking on top of each other instead of being located alongside one another in the same row. This is despite me copying and pasting the exact code from the tutorial. 6+6=12 so I expect them to fit on one row but they do not. It's really frustrating. What am I missing? I've tried two tutorials, exactly, and I get the same result.

[Screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qQ7a.jpg)

```
    <div class="container">

        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p>Asymmetrical YOLO banjo lomo fanny pack, shoreditch flexitarian enter code heredreamcatcher ethnic kitsch sriracha nisi sustainable swag. Cliche 90's farm-to-table master cleanse Pinterest jean shorts. Cillum raw denim aesthetic sunt.</p>

                <p>Aliqua photo booth literally veniam minim leggings, est craft beer `enter code here`banjo intelligentsia Truffaut officia. r.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p>Consectetur art party Tonx culpa semiotics.</p>

                <p>Wayfarers selvage YOLO, commodo assumenda eu est bespoke mlkshk.</p>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Check your browser console for errors: The HTML markup is fine: http://www.bootply.com/122866

Comment: Thanks Skelly. I found the solution. Because I was using BS via NetDNA CDN I had to adjust to '<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />' and include "http:" ahead of "//..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example works for me. Make sure you have the bootstrap stylesheet correctly referenced.

http://www.bootply.com/122865

Comment: Thanks that was the issue. Because I am on localhost I needed to change the link to the CDN.

Comment: Your very welcome. You can also link locally just make sure you have the direct path to bootstrap.